# How to convert tostring from JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want to send the rows to jsp from selected checkbox in jstl .After getting the selected row value need to send it to jsp request.So i would to convert to toString.

if i use `<c:out value="${product.tostring()` getting EL error.Please advise.

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="product">
<td><input type="text" value='${product.featurename}' name="<c:out value="${product.featurename}" />" readonly="readonly"/></td>
<td><input type="text" value='${product.featureversion}' readonly="readonly"/></td>
<td><input type="text" value='${product.end_date}' readonly="readonly"/></td>
<td><input type="text" value='${product.new_end_date}' class="datepicker" name="<c:out value="${product.new_end_date}" />"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="<c:out value="${product}" />" name="newenddate" class="selectedId"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only use

```
<input type="checkbox" value="${product}"/>
```

Comment: As @Alex says EL call toString() method implicitly

Comment: Getting from jstl using String[] newenddate = req.getParameterValues("newenddate"); , bean class"product".How to iterate the that values ?

Comment: Please, Can you explain better the question, or post a new answer to be more legible and appropiate.

Answer (score 1):

`${product}` will call method `toString()` implicitly.